# How to search between a combination of varchar and numeric values in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

So, I know this is bad database design but unfortunately this is what I have to use for my job, and I'm struggling to figure it out.

I'm writing a sql query that checks if the value of a certain field is between two values.

```
Select * 
from TestTable 
where TestField between ValueA and ValueB
```

The only problem is that ValueA and ValueB and TestField can be either integers or varchars. They can either be something like 100 or something like X100. Values that start with X are greater than any integer without an X.

So, if ValueA is 100 and ValueB is 2000, I want to return all rows where Testfield is between 100 and 2000.

However, if ValueA is 100 and ValueB is X500, I want to return all integers greater than 100 and all values that start with X and the trailing number less than 500.

For example the order would be, from smallest to greatest:

```
1. 100
2. 500
3. 1000
4. 5000
5. X100
6. X500
7. X1000
8. X2000
```

So, for my question: **How could I write a query that accurately searches between ValueA and ValueB?**

With valueA and valueB as varchars it prevents me from accurately checking which numbers are greater.

Comment: Where are these `ValueA` and `ValueB` coming from? Whatever language/script is writing this SQL is going to need to be more creative about this WHERE clause.

Comment: They are getting ValueA and ValueB from a c# application, which uses the values to build the query.

Comment: My best call would be to add a function to your database and then use it in the query. I don't have time to create you one right now, but I'll see tonight if your question does not have an answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
DECLARE
@Test TABLE
    (
         TestField VARCHAR(10)
    );

INSERT INTO
    @Test (TestField)
VALUES
    ('100'), ('500'), ('1000'), ('X10'), ('X500'), ('X3')
;

SELECT
     TestField
FROM
    @Test
ORDER BY
     CASE
         WHEN LEFT(TestField, 1) = 'X'
             THEN 1
         ELSE 0
     END
    ,CAST(REPLACE(TestField, 'X', '') AS INTEGER)
```

Basically, you're ordering first based upon whether it begins with an "X" or not, then removing the "X" and ordering it by its integer value.

Comment: That is very nice.

Comment: Thank you for the well thought out answer John!

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be a good idea to handle the building of the WHERE clause on the application side in C#.

```
sqlstring="SELECT * FROM table WHERE ";

If (Regex.Matches(yourstring2,@"[a-zA-Z]").Count > 0) {
    sqlstring=sqlstring + " testfield > @param1a OR testfield BETWEEN @param2a AND param2b"
} else {
    sqlstring=sqlstring + " testfield BETWEEN @param1 AND @param2"
}
```

Then you can bind with similar logic

```
yourstring1=500;
yourstring2="x5000";

If (Regex.Matches(yourstring2,@"[a-zA-Z]").Count > 0) {
    command.Parameters.Add("@param1a", SqlDbType.Int);
    command.Parameters["@param1a"].Value = yourstring1;        

    command.Parameters.Add("@param2a", SqlDbType.Varchar);
    command.Parameters["@param2a"].Value = yourstring2.substring(1,1) + "0";
    command.Parameters.Add("@param2b", SqlDbType.Varchar);
    command.Parameters["@param2b"].value = yourstring2;
} else {

    command.Parameters.Add("@param1", SqlDbType.Int);
    command.Parameters["@param1"].Value = yourstring1;

    command.Parameters.Add("@param2", SqlDbType.Int);
    command.Parameters["@param2"].value = yourstring2;
}
```

My C# is rusty at best, so I'm 100% certain that the syntax is off here and there is a much more elegant way to write this, but... the gist is the same. The programming language feels like the right place to do this instead of the SQL where this *may* be possible, but it's going to be really ugly and potentially error prone. In C# we have all the info needed and a lot of nuanced control that we are lacking on the SQL side.

And that's coming from someone that is generally berating people for trying to do things on the application side that should be done in the database.

Comment: Thank you for the well thought out answer JNevill!